# How to work with conditional expectations and variances?

Tags: variance, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

I have seen this statement in a [lecture note](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/ADAfaEPoV/ADAfaEPoV.pdf) :

$$E[(Y-f(X))^2\,|\,X]=Var[Y|X]+E^2[(Y-f(X)\,|\,X]]$$

If $Z,X$ are random variables, then shouldn't be 
$Var[Z|X]=E[Z^2|X]-E^2[Z|X]$?In which case shouldn't the term $Var[Y|X]$ be $Var[Y-f(X)\,|\,X]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the equation known to you, viz. 
$\operatorname{var}(Z\mid X) = E[Z^2\mid X] - \left(E[Z\mid X]\right)^2$
and re-write it as follows.

$$\begin{align}
E[Z^2\mid X] &= \operatorname{var}(Z\mid X) + \left(E[Z\mid X]\right)^2\\
E[(Y-f(X))^2\mid X] &= \operatorname{var}((Y-f(X))\mid X) + \left(E[(Y-f(X))\mid X]\right)^2 &\scriptstyle{\text{substitute}~ Y-f(X)~\text{for}~Z}\\
\end{align}$$

Now, notice that the first term on the right is a *conditional* variance
-- the (conditional) variance of $Y-f(X)$, in fact, --  *given* the value of $X$. But if $X$
has value $x$, say, then $f(X)$ is a constant (let's call it $a$), and
not a random variable at all. Thus, the *conditional* variance of $Y-f(X)$ 
*given* that $X = x$ is the same as the  *conditional* variance of 
$Y-a$ given that $X=x$.
But, variance is invariant to translation of the data set (that is, $Y$ and
$Y-a$ have the same variance), and thus we get
$$E[(Y-f(X))^2\mid X] = \operatorname{var}(Y\mid X) + \left(E[(Y-f(X))\mid X]\right)^2 $$
which is what your lecture note asserts.